# Resizing images from jQuery src

Tags: jquery, google-maps, instagram

With the following code I display some images as a custom marker on a Google Maps.
The problem is: I want the pictures to be (for example) 25 by 25px.

```
$(".insta-img").each(function() {
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = this.src;

    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng($(this).data('min-lat'),$(this).data('min-lng'));
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map,
        icon: image.src
    });
    gmarkers.push(marker);
});
```

How can I resize these images?

Comment: try size: sizeM -> sizeL ?

Comment: @thenewseattle My mistake.. I should had deleted the code 'size:sizeM'

Comment: can you post a fiddle?

Comment: Don't think thats gonna work. The thing I am working on is a web application which combines the Google Maps API with the Instagram API. Basically I want to display pictures from Instagram on the Maps of Google (through location based data). 

The problem I have now is that the pictures are taken from the source (read: images are from my webpage, which have the url from Instagram), and are 150x150px. I'd like to see them at 25px (only 25px on the Google Maps as a Custom Marker).

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer! And because I want to edit the size of the custom Google Marker, I need to do the following thing/have the following code:

```
var image = new Image();
image.src = this.src;

var pinIcon = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
    image.src,
    null, /* size is determined at runtime */
    null, /* origin is 0,0 */
    null, /* anchor is bottom center of the scaled image */
    new google.maps.Size(50, 50)
);  

var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng($(this).data('min-lat'),$(this).data('min-lng'));
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
    icon: pinIcon
});
gmarkers.push(marker);
```